# When moving a views to a new directory, what changes must I make for them to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, directory

To be specific I simply created a subdirectory in the one they were currently contained in and I am now getting

Missing template users/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en]....

I assume I need to make a simple change elsewhere so rails knows where to find the views however I have not been able to figure it out.

Edit: to elaborate further, its not all of them, just a specific group that I wanted to organize.

Edit2: to elaborate even further... the path to these views is users_path, and I need to somehow update it so that it knows where to find the views. Would this be in the routes?

Edit3:

in the users_controller.rb i tried:

```
render view/index.html.erb
```

and got the error

**undefined local variable or method `view'**

i also tried

```
render :partial => "view/index.html.erb"
```

and got the error

**undefined method `render'**

Edit4:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless @user == current_user
      redirect_to :back, :alert => "Access denied."
    end
  end
end
```

Edit5:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Users</h3>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <tr>
                <%= render user %>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in the appropriate place of your controller: e.g., `render 'subfolder/view_file'`. If you don't specify this in the controller, Rails will look for the default location for the view (so you need to specify this if the view is not in the default location). So if it's the index view that you've relocated, you need to specify generally at the end of the index method in the controller, which view it needs to render: `render 'subfolder/index'`.

If the relocated view is a partial, you would need to specify the path to this partial there where you call for the partial.

It's not in the routes where you need to make adjustments: in routes you specify which controller method to execute as a user visits a certain url of your website.

Comment: Thanks alot! I feel like I'm so close but I just cant seem to get it right.  See my edits if you feel up to it.

Comment: What if you try `render 'view/index'` (so with the ')? 
If this doesn't work, could you specify the exact path of the view file and the corresponding controller method?

Comment: No dice, just to clarify, that should be added to the show method, right? The path is users_path, Im adding the controller above

Comment: If you enter in the Terminal `rake routes` you can see all your routes. I expect that the users_path will refer to the `index method` in the controller and not to the `show method`. The path to the `show method` would generally be `user_path` (singular instead of plural). Could you also post the full path to the view file you’re testing? So for example: app/views/etc.

Comment: users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index

Comment: theapp/app/views/users/view

Comment: But yea the reason its not plural is because the view is actually for viewing all of the users, sorry i can see how that may have been confusing.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your index method should be: `def index` `@users = User.all` `render 'view/index'` `end`. If this doesn't work you could also try: `render 'users/view/index'`. I assumed here that the name of the view file is index.html.erb.

Comment: render 'users/view/index' worked! Only now im getting a missing template error in the index view that was not there before... It works if i just remove the code from the index page. I Added the code above if you want to take a look, thanks for your help either way! Also, is it a bad idea to be doing all this stuff just because I like the files organized a certain way? Could it create problems down the line?

Comment: Like should i just start this part of the code from scratch and have them end up in the right folders? if thats possible?

Comment: In your index view file you have the line `<%= render user %>`. This will call for a partial: `app/views/users/_user.html.erb`. I guess this partial does not exist or is in a different folder (you might want to open a new question for this).  Could it create problems down the line? I'm not that experienced myself to fully comment on this. But I've always understood that the whole idea of Rails is to stay close to its RESTful setup, so I wouldn't recommend for it (but either way, it's a good exercise to learn to understand routes/rendering).

Comment: Alright thanks alot for all you help! but yea Im definitely mainly focused on figuring out why this does/doesnt work and the best way to do it